# How to disable swiping when on form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I am trying to swipe pages by using code found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/26/draggable-dual-view-slideshow/).
I've attempted to make use of only the part where it enables horizontal swiping.
Then I ran into a problem.
What I'm trying to do is to include form tags within the div swiped, but the code doesn't allow even input tags in the div to be focused and typed.

So far, I tried to limit targeted elements by doing:

```
1. replacing     
  // the slides
  this.slides = [].slice.call( this.handle.children );
/*with*/   
  // the slides
  var slides = [].slice.call( this.imgDragger.querySelectorAll('div.handle>*:not(form)') );

2. adding
  if (slide.tagName.toLowerCase() == "form") { return }
/*and*/
  if (currentSlide .tagName.toLowerCase() == "form") { return }

/*after*/
  slide.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
/*and*/
  currentSlide = self.slides[ self.current ];
/*respectively.*/
```

But these wouldn't do the job for me :(
Can someone help me revise the code so it can disable swiping on form tags?

Below is the structure of my html.

```
<body>
    <div id="slideshow" class="dragslider">
      <section class="img-dragger img-dragger-large dragdealer">
        <div class="handle">            
          <div class="slide">           
            <div class="img-wrap">
                swiping page #1
              <form><input type="text" /></form>

            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="slide">                           
            <div class="img-wrap">
                swiping page #2                     
            </div>                          
          </div>
        </div>
      </section><!-- /img-dragger-->
    </div>
    <script>
        (function() {                   

            var toggleBtnn = function() {
                    if( slideshow.isFullscreen ) {
                        classie.add( switchBtnn, 'view-maxi' );
                    }
                    else {
                        classie.remove( switchBtnn, 'view-maxi' );
                    }
                },
                slideshow = new DragSlideshow( document.getElementById( 'slideshow' ), { 
                    // toggle between fullscreen and minimized slideshow
                    onToggle : toggleBtnn                                               

                }),
                toggleSlideshow = function() {                  

                    slideshow.toggle();
                    toggleBtnn();

                }                   

            // toggle between fullscreen and small slideshow
            switchBtnn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleSlideshow )         

        }());           
    </script>   
</body>
```

And here's dragslideshow.js :

```
/**
 * dragslideshow.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2014, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    var docElem = window.document.documentElement,
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    /**
     * gets the viewport width and height
     * based on http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/
     */
    function getViewport( axis ) {
        var client, inner;
        if( axis === 'x' ) {
            client = docElem['clientWidth'];
            inner = window['innerWidth'];
        }
        else if( axis === 'y' ) {
            client = docElem['clientHeight'];
            inner = window['innerHeight'];
        }

        return client < inner ? inner : client;
    }

    /**
     * extend obj function
     */
    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * DragSlideshow function
     */
    function DragSlideshow( el, options ) { 
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    /**
     * DragSlideshow options
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype.options = {
        perspective : '1200',
        slideshowRatio : 0.3, // between: 0,1
        onToggle : function() { return false; },
        onToggleContent : function() { return false; },
        onToggleContentComplete : function() { return false; }
    }

    /**
     * init function
     * initialize and cache some vars
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._init = function() {
        var self = this;

        // current
        this.current = 0;

        // status
        this.isFullscreen = true;

        // the images wrapper element
        this.imgDragger = this.el.querySelector( 'section.dragdealer' );

        // the moving element inside the images wrapper
        this.handle = this.imgDragger.querySelector( 'div.handle' );

        // the slides
        this.slides = [].slice.call( this.handle.children );

        // total number of slides
        this.slidesCount = this.slides.length;

        if( this.slidesCount < 1 ) return;

        // cache options slideshowRatio (needed for window resize)
        this.slideshowRatio = this.options.slideshowRatio;

        // add class "current" to first slide
        classie.add( this.slides[ this.current ], 'current' );

        // the pages/content
        this.pages = this.el.querySelector( 'section.pages' );

        // set the width of the handle : total slides * 100%
        this.handle.style.width = this.slidesCount * 100 + '%';

        // set the width of each slide to 100%/total slides
        this.slides.forEach( function( slide ) {
            slide.style.width = 100 / self.slidesCount + '%';
        } );

        // initialize the DragDealer plugin
        this._initDragDealer();

        // init events
        this._initEvents();
    }

    /**
     * initialize the events
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        this.slides.forEach( function( slide ) {
            // clicking the slides when not in isFullscreen mode
            slide.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                if( self.isFullscreen || self.dd.activity || self.isAnimating ) return false;

                if( self.slides.indexOf( slide ) === self.current ) {
                    self.toggle();
                }
                else {
                    self.dd.setStep( self.slides.indexOf( slide ) + 1 );
                }
            } );

            // reveal content
            slide.querySelector( 'button.content-switch' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._toggleContent( slide ); } );
        } );

        // keyboard navigation events
        document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
            var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which,
                currentSlide = self.slides[ self.current ];

            if( self.isContent ) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    // up key
                    case 38:
                        // only if current scroll is 0:
                        if( self._getContentPage( currentSlide ).scrollTop === 0 ) {
                            self._toggleContent( currentSlide );
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            else {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    // down key
                    case 40:
                        // if not fullscreen don't reveal the content. If you want to navigate directly to the content then remove this check.
                        if( !self.isFullscreen ) return;
                        self._toggleContent( currentSlide );
                        break;
                    // right and left keys
                    case 37:
                        self.dd.setStep( self.current );
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        self.dd.setStep( self.current + 2 );
                        break;
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * gets the content page of the current slide
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._getContentPage = function( slide ) {
        return this.pages.querySelector( 'div.content[data-content = "' + slide.getAttribute( 'data-content' ) + '"]' );
    }

    /**
     * show/hide content
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._toggleContent = function( slide ) {
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;

        // callback
        this.options.onToggleContent();

        // get page
        var page = this._getContentPage( slide );

        if( this.isContent ) {
            // enable the dragdealer
            this.dd.enable();
            classie.remove( this.el, 'show-content' );
        }
        else {
            // before: scroll all the content up
            page.scrollTop = 0;
            // disable the dragdealer
            this.dd.disable();
            classie.add( this.el, 'show-content' ); 
            classie.add( page, 'show' );
        }

        var self = this,
            onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) === -1 || ev.target !== this ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                if( self.isContent ) {
                    classie.remove( page, 'show' ); 
                }
                self.isContent = !self.isContent;
                self.isAnimating = false;
                // callback
                self.options.onToggleContentComplete();
            };

        if( support.transitions ) {
            this.el.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }

    /**
     * initialize the Dragdealer plugin
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._initDragDealer = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.dd = new Dragdealer( this.imgDragger, {
            steps: this.slidesCount,
            speed: 0.4,
            loose: true,
            requestAnimationFrame : true,
            callback: function( x, y ) {
                self._navigate( x, y );
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * DragDealer plugin callback: update current value
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._navigate = function( x, y ) {
        // add class "current" to the current slide / remove that same class from the old current slide
        classie.remove( this.slides[ this.current || 0 ], 'current' );
        this.current = this.dd.getStep()[0] - 1;
        classie.add( this.slides[ this.current ], 'current' );
    }

    /**
     * toggle between fullscreen and minimized slideshow
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype.toggle = function() {
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;

        // add preserve-3d to the slides (seems to fix a rendering problem in firefox)
        this._preserve3dSlides( true );

        // callback
        this.options.onToggle();

        classie.remove( this.el, this.isFullscreen ? 'switch-max' : 'switch-min' );
        classie.add( this.el, this.isFullscreen ? 'switch-min' : 'switch-max' );

        var self = this,
            p = this.options.perspective,
            r = this.options.slideshowRatio,
            zAxisVal = this.isFullscreen ? p - ( p / r ) : p - p * r;

        this.imgDragger.style.WebkitTransform = 'perspective(' + this.options.perspective + 'px) translate3d( -50%, -50%, ' + zAxisVal + 'px )';
        this.imgDragger.style.transform = 'perspective(' + this.options.perspective + 'px) translate3d( -50%, -50%, ' + zAxisVal + 'px )';

        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) === -1 ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }

            if( !self.isFullscreen ) {
                // remove preserve-3d to the slides (seems to fix a rendering problem in firefox)
                self._preserve3dSlides();
            }

            // replace class "img-dragger-large" with "img-dragger-small"
            classie.remove( this, self.isFullscreen ? 'img-dragger-large' : 'img-dragger-small' );
            classie.add( this, self.isFullscreen ? 'img-dragger-small' : 'img-dragger-large' );

            // reset transforms and set width & height
            self.imgDragger.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0px )';
            self.imgDragger.style.transform = 'translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0px )';
            this.style.width = self.isFullscreen ? self.options.slideshowRatio * 100 + '%' : '100%';
            this.style.height = self.isFullscreen ? self.options.slideshowRatio * 100 + '%' : '100%';
            // reinstatiate the dragger with the "reflow" method
            self.dd.reflow();

            // change status
            self.isFullscreen = !self.isFullscreen;

            self.isAnimating = false;
        };

        if( support.transitions ) {
            this.imgDragger.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }

    /**
     * add/remove preserve-3d to the slides (seems to fix a rendering problem in firefox)
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._preserve3dSlides = function( add ) {
        this.slides.forEach( function( slide ) {
            slide.style.transformStyle = add ? 'preserve-3d' : '';
        });
    }

    /**
     * add to global namespace
     */
    window.DragSlideshow = DragSlideshow;

} )( window );
```

I realize this is such a long question.
But if you can please help me, I will very much appreciate you since I've been working to fix the problem for a week now.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The project is on GitHub and there are no instructions. You could have saved a week by raising the issue to the projects owener here -- https://github.com/codrops/DraggableDualViewSlideshow/issues

Comment: @Tasos thanks for your comment. I just raised an issue although I'm not sure if she will respond at all.

Comment: the owner of the project should answer quick because the question is easy to understand.